# Firestore, Avoid requerying data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Forgive me but this is a supper basic question, I couldn't really find a good explanation..

Say I am querying a collection looking for certain attributes, and I return some results that match that.

Then I requery looking for some different attributes, some of which will have the same results.

Is there a way to avoid redownloading that data? some of my results will have already been loaded to the users phone. Does that make sense? Basically looking for a way to cache data and not have to worry about pulling the same data twice

Comment: This is a very broad question. Can you provide some details as to why you want to do this? What does the affect of pulling the data twice have. Are you 'pulling' a million nodes and concerned about exceeding the capacity of the device?

Comment: Sorry, yeah... I am building an app like reddit in a ways where there is a 'hot' feed as well as a 'new' feed. So the user can switch back and forth between the two of those.. in this case, sometimes stuff that will be under hot will also be under new.. to me if theres a way to reavoid downloading sstuff that filtered under hot, when I switch to new, I feel like it would be a better user expierence? is this not common practice? maybe i should just redownload upon each switch..

Comment: definetly not pulling millions of nodes though.. maybe 100 max and not even that

Comment: I don't know how your query is set up, but if it's .child added then you can ignore the snapshots that are already in the app. If it's less than  couple thousand it would be more code than it's worth to try to filter them so I would suggest just reloading.

Comment: yeah, in that case maybe just do a full reload.. the more i think about it.. each will just be a little piece of text (think a tweet without pictures) so it probably will be pretty insignifcant